# Storing data coming form cupcarbon into database

Tags: iot

I am creating an IoT simulation using Cupcarbon IoT simulator. I want to store the simulation data in some database. Anyone, please help me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to use the command *printfile*.

With this command you will able to store in the file with the name results some data you will choose. Every sensor node could have its own result file.

Hope this works for you. 
I would love to ready if you found another solution.

BR